# Android: How to set inner boarder shadow in a drawable?

Tags: android, drawable, gradient, shadow

I want to create an inner boarder shadow to a layout. However so far no luck. Currently I am testing a drawable but the effect is not as pleasant as expected.

Here is my attempt:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item>
    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
           android:shape="rectangle">
        <gradient
            android:startColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:centerColor="#000000"
            android:endColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:angle="0" />
    </shape>
</item>
<item
    android:bottom="20dp"
    android:left="20dp"
    android:right="20dp"
    android:top="20dp">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="#70D159"/>
    </shape>
</item>
```

I want to achieve something like this:

[image]

Is there a better approach to achieve this? Thank you in advance!

Comment: you can make a gradient and use it.

Comment: @KaranMer Yes but I down know how to set it properly

Comment: you need to make the resources file and set the drawable as background of your widget.

Comment: @KaranMer Yes that is quite obvious but I am struggling with the setting of the gradient as I mentioned in my previous comment.

Comment: do not use shape drawable. you need to design it using photoshop.